# selenium 3.4 with Safari 11 compatibility issues

Tags: macos, compatibility, selenium3, safari-11

We are having lot of tests failing with the combination of selenium 3.4 with Safari 11 browser on Mac OS Sierra, where almost all other browsers are working more or less reasonably OK. 
Is there any special wiki, forum or location which explains what are the compatibility issues between them and how to resolve them ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue related with Selenium Browser compatibility. Try to upgrade Selenium version to 3.9.1 or even higher 3.11.0 (which is compliance with the w3c standard)